# orbits and decomposition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, rotations

so I don't understand this clearly. Why are there two orbits with order 5? I understand that rotating a dodecahedron with one face means rotation of other faces too. That is why the rotation group on them acts transitively in my opinion. But why two orbits of order 5? could not they be merged in one orbit? Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I mean, is it the only representation of $S$ in this case? can't $S$ be represented as 6 + 6? like $H$ and its adjacent 5 faces and its opposite $H'$ and its adjacent 5 faces?

Comment: You may be misunderstanding what $H$ is. $H$ is not a face, instead it is a group, namely $H$ is the group of rotations of the dodecahedron that stabilizer a particular face $s$.

Comment: yes, I know that. It was my error. I should have written $s$ and $s'$ instead of $H$ and $H'$. The question still remains.

Comment: $H$ has two fixed points, which are opposite faces, say $s$ and $s'$. Of the remaining $10$ faces, $5$ have an edge in common with $s$ and the other $5$ have an edge in common with $s'$ These form the two orbits of $H$ of order $5$.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But what if I say that $s$ and its adjacent 5 faces and  $s'$ and its adjacent 5 faces make two orbits of order 6? will it be false?

Comment: Yes it is false, because $\{ s \}$ and $\{ s' \}$ are orbits of length $1$.

Comment: The subgroup $H$ consists of five elements, namely the rotations of the dodecahedron that rotate the face $s$ through the five angles $\{2 k \pi / 5 \mid k=0,1,2,3,4\}$. Each of those rotations fixes $s$, so $\{s\}$ is an orbit of length $1$ of the subgroup $H$. The five faces of the dodecahedron just below $s$ form a single orbit of length $5$ of the subgroup $H$. When you form a set of size $6$ by taking the face $s$ together with the $5$ faces just below $s$, *you do not get a single orbit*, you simply have a union of two disjoint orbits.

Comment: Yes, yes! now everything is clear! Thanks a lot everyone!